# How to store data in database using redbeans php

Tags: php

I am trying to store data from my web form to database using redbeans but I cannot make it work. I have already make sure that database is connected. I am using apache xampp server for web and sql.
This is my code

**Form**

```php
<head>
</head>
<?php
    require "validatecar.php";
?>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    Model <input type="text" name="Model">
    Manufacturing Company <input type="text" name="Company">
    Pessenger Capacity <input type="number" name="Pessenger">
    Luggage Capacty <input type="number" name="Luggage">
    Doors <input type="number" name="Doors">
    Transmission <input type="text" name="Transmission">
    Stereo <input type="text" name="Stereo">
    Air Conditioning <input type="text" name="AC">
    Image <input type="file" name="Image">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

**Validate**

```php
<?php
    include "dbconnection.php";
?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {

        $model = $_POST['Model'];
        $company = $_POST['Company'];
        $pessenger = $_POST['Pessenger'];
        $luggage = $_POST['Luggage'];
        $doors = $_POST['Doors'];
        $transmission = $_POST['Transmission'];
        $stereo = $_POST['Stereo'];
        $ac = $_POST['AC'];
        $image = $_POST['Image'];

        $cars = R::dispense('cars');
        $cars->model = $model;
        $cars->company = $company;
        $cars->pessenger = $pessenger;
        $cars->luggage = $luggage;
        $cars->doors = $doors;
        $cars->transmission = $transmission;
        $cars->stereo = $stereo;
        $cars->ac = $ac;
        $cars->image = $image;
        R::store($cars);

        R::close();
    }
?>
```

If you could tell me what am I doing wrong and how to solve it, that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gone for naming using first letter capital. But for some reason your name for your submit fails your naming convention.

You are looking for `$_POST['Submit']` when you have named it all lower case `'submit'` instead of `Submit` so your code for storing in your Database will never run.

If you were to perform a var_dump() or print_r() on $_POST.

I.E. in your validate.php for instance, prior to your if test, you will see what is being "Posted".

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);  // Added for Debug - View what is being posted.
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    { 
    //... Rest of code here
```

So in your form, your submit input has a wee typo for your "name" value.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

should be...

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
```